# Google Drive API: How do you insert permissions to make a document publicly readable?

Tags: google-drive-api, user-permissions

I know that to add permissions to a specific user, you format a permissions resource like so:

```
new_permission = {
    'value': 'me@gmail.com',
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'reader'
}
```

But, what if i want to grant read-only access to anyone?  I guess, something like:

```
new_permission = {
    'type': 'anyone',
    'role': 'reader',
    'value': ???!
}
```

What do I put as 'value'?

Comment: this is the closest i got to solving this :P is this the js library? where do you put the request?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that "value" is not required parameter for type=anyone.

```
new_permission = {
    'type': 'anyone',
    'role': 'reader'
}
```

works just fine.